# Given $\epsilon>0$, if $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ does $\|f-\sum_{i=1}^n g_i^2\|\leq\epsilon$ for some $g_i$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is an old qual problem from 2010 at my school.

> Show that given a real-valued continuosu function on $[0,1]^2$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exist real-valued continuous functions $g_1,\dots,g_n$ and $h_1,\dots,h_n$ on $[0,1]$ 
>   for some finite $n\geq 1$ so that
>   $$
> \left|f(x,y)-\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)g_i(y)\right|\leq\epsilon, 0\leq x,y\leq 1.
> $$
>
> If $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $0\leq x,y\leq 1$, can this be done with $f_i=g_i$ for each $i$?

I let $A$ be the subalgebra of $C([0,1]^2,\mathbb{R})$ generated by functions $fg$ where $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R}$ and $g\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $fg(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.

I claim
$A$ separates points. If $(x_1,y_1)\neq (x_2,y_2)$, then define $f=id$ and $g\equiv 1$. then if $x_1\neq x_2$, 
$fg(x_1,y_1)=x_1$ and $fg(x_2,y_2)=x_2$. If $x_1=x_2$, then necessarily $y_1\neq y_2$, so define $f\equiv 1$ and $g=id$. Then $fg(x_1,y_1)=y_1$ and $fg(x_2,y_2)=y_2$. 
So $A$ separates points, so by Stone-Weierstrass, $A$ is dense in $C([0,1]^2,\mathbb{R})$, so given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $\|f-\sum f_ig_i\|\leq\epsilon$
for some $f_i,g_i$. Then the conclusion would follow.

However, if $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ can we make sure $f_i=g_i$? The only thing I noticed was that the graph $f$ is symmetric about the line $y=x$, and of course $\sum f_ig_i$ is nonnegative. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the subspace $S \subset C([0,1]^2,\mathbb{R})$ of symmetric functions is isometrically isomorphic to $C(\Delta, \mathbb{R})$, where $\Delta := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \leqslant y \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \}$.

Let $A \subset C(\Delta,\mathbb{R})$ be the subalgebra generated by $\mathcal{P} = \{ P(f) : f \in C([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \}$, where

$$P(f) \colon (x,y) \mapsto f(x)\cdot f(y).$$

It remains to see that $\mathcal{P}$ separates points. Consider $f_a \colon x \mapsto a + x$.

If $(x,y)$ and $(s,t)$ are two points (not necessarily distinct) in $\Delta$ such that $P(f_1)(x,y) = P(f_1)(s,t)$ and $P(f_2)(x,y) = P(f_2)(s,t)$, then

$$\begin{align}
(1+x)(1+y) = (1+s)(1+t) &\Rightarrow x+y+xy = s+t+st,\tag{1}\\
(2+x)(2+y) = (2+s)(2+t) &\Rightarrow 2x+2y+xy = 2s+2t+st.\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ yields $x+y = s+t$, and hence also $xy = st$. Then also $(x-y)^2 = (x+y)^2 - 4xy = (s+t)^2 - 4st = (s-t)^2$, and since $y \leqslant x$ and $t \leqslant s$, that implies $x-y = s-t$. But

$$(x+y = s+t) \land (x-y) = (s-t) \Rightarrow (x,y) = (s,t).$$

So $\mathcal{P}$ separates points, and hence the subalgebra generated by $\mathcal{P}$ is dense. $P(f)$ is mapped under the isometric isomorphism $\varphi \colon C(\Delta,\mathbb{R}) \to S$ to the function $\tilde{P}(f) \colon (x,y) \mapsto f(x)f(y)$.